# Replace the row in the first dataframe with the same rowname from second dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, for example:

```
test1 <- matrix(c(1:9), nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("att", "btt", "ctt"), c("A", "B", "C")))
```

```
     A  B  C
att  1  4  7
btt  2  5  8
ctt  3  6  9
```

```
test2 <- matrix(c(1:6), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("att", "ctt"), c("A", "B", "C")))
```

```
     A  B  C
att  1  3  5  
ctt  2  4  6
```

I want to replace the row in test1 from test2, which have the same rowname. The results would like this:

```
     A  B  C
att  1  3  5
btt  2  5  8
ctt  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `row.names` of 'test2' as the `i`, subset the columns of 'test1' and assign that with 'test2'

```
test1[row.names(test2),] <- test2
test1
#     A B C
#  att 1 3 5
#  btt 2 5 8
#  ctt 2 4 6
```